# Python starred expression inside function not working

Tags: python, list

When I run this code on Python 3.5 I get

NameError name 'md' is not defined.

I have used a starred expression for md so it will grab all 
of the middle values. Since it didn't work, I tried using a starred
expression in the code above the function (drop_first_last), and that starred expression worked fine.

```
t = [3, 5, 6,8, 2, 9]
first, *middle, last = t
avgg = np.mean(middle)
print('middle is:', middle)
print('avg  is:', avgg)
def drop_first_last(t):
    frst, *md, lst = t
    return  np.mean(md)

drop_first_last(t)
print("avg",md)
```

Comment: `md` is defined ***locally*** inside the `drop_first_last` function and cannot be accessed outside the function, unless you _globalize_ it. I don't recommend the latter at all.

Comment: Notice that if you put the `print("avg",md)` call inside the `drop_first_last()` definition (after `md` is defined) it'll work. The issue, as @Abdou said, is that `md` is only available inside the function, not after it returns.

Comment: So, just to be sure I understand, then typically you would use a print value inside the function(?) or use a return statement to get the values out of the function?

Comment: Yuu can also get the same "drop-first-and-last" behavior with `t[1:-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

The scope of `md` is limited to the namespace inside the `drop_first_last` function and cannot be accessed outside the latter, unless you consider *globalizing* it. That aside, it does not seem to me that you are looking to `print` the list `md` itself. What I think you are trying to do is print the average of the elements of the list. So, instead of:

```
drop_first_last(t)
print("avg is: ",md)
```

do:

```
print("avg is: ",drop_first_last(t))
```

But if you *really* are after the `md` variable defined inside the `drop_first_last` function, then you can redefine your function as follows:

```
def drop_first_last(t):
  global md
  frst, *md, lst = t
  return  np.mean(md)
```

With the function defined this way, you can now access the `md` variable (which is a `list`).

```
t = [3, 5, 6, 8, 2, 9]
print(drop_first_last(t))
print(md)
```

yields:

```
#5.25
#[5, 6, 8, 2]
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Great answer except you introduced `global` which is almost always the Wrong Thing in Python. If you want two results from a function you can have them. I'd prefer to see `return (md, np.mean(md))`